# How can I select a solution that satisfies a particular set of conditions?

Tags: equation-solving

I am solving a Kuhn-Tucker problem and the list of potential solutions is vast. I've been searching on these forums for a while and still cannot figure out a good way to select particular solutions based on conditions. For instance this is my code and I get many solutions and want to remove all in which $i = 0$:

```
FullSimplify[Solve[
  {((-(θ*(-1 + μ) - μ))*(-1 + λ1) - (-1 + θ)*μ*λ2)*d2R == 0, 
   ((-1 + θ)*(-1 + μ)*(-1 + λ1 + λ2) - λ4)*d2r == 0,
   (r*(-1 + θ)*(-1 + μ) + R*(θ + μ - θ*μ) - λ1 + (-1 + θ)*λ2 - λ3 + r*λ4)*i == 0, 
   λ1*(i - μ*d2R - (1 - μ)*(θ*d2R + (1 - θ)*d2r)) == 0,
   λ2*(-c - (-1 + θ)*(i + d2r*(-1 + μ) - d2R*μ)) == 0, 
   λ3*(i - 1) == 0,
   λ4*(d2r - i*r) == 0},
  {i, d2R, d2r, λ1, λ2, λ3, λ4}]]
```

Comment: Please look at the instructions here to copy readable code from MMA:
https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site

Comment: your code not looking readable look at above then edit your question please

Comment: Sorry about that - I tried following that but not sure how I can get the greek letters shown. Thank you for your help

Comment: greek letter are all right

Comment: The system of equations/inequalities provided to `Solve` can include inequations (see documentation for `Solve`); consequently, include the inequation `i != 0` in the system. The solutions will not include any for which `i = 0` and there will be no need to delete any of the solutions.

Comment: Thank you Bob - sorry for the silly question I just have some trouble reading the documentation but I now see exactly what you mean. That certainly makes solving Kuhn Tucker problems much easier

Comment: Hi Bob - I am using your suggestion to include inequalities/inequations (i.e. parameter restrictions etc) in Solve but it takes forever for it to find a solution.  Do you have any suggestions on how to make it faster (i.e. maybe solving first then applying inequalities to remove unwanted solutions)? Sorry if this is again a novice question and I don't want to take up too much of your time. I appreciate it nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

If `S` are your solutions, from

```
S = FullSimplify[Solve[...
```

then you can delete those with $i=0$ with

```
DeleteCases[S, _?((i /. #) == 0 &)]
```

(15 solutions)

Comment: Thank you so much that's exactly what I needed!